# composer.json file deleted any way to recover it?

Tags: php, json, composer-php

i managed to re make my composer.json file

I was working on a project, by mistake, the main composer file was deleted.
cannot recover it manually, I still have vendor folders and files now I cannot add anything else because it will delete the current vendors is there any way to regenerate the composer file with vendors included in it?

now im getting

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
FatalErrorException in Controller.php line 27:
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\getcong()


{
    "name": "testing/test",
    "description": "test",
    "keywords": ["test"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "SocialiteProviders/Manager": "^2.1",
        "Simexis/Installer": "^1.6",
        "Laravel/Socialite": "^2.0",
        "Intervention/Image": "^2.3",
        "Illuminate/Html": "^5.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",
        "terbium/db-config": "^2.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.*",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^6.21",
        "socialiteproviders/vkontakte": "^2.0"
    },
      "require-dev": {
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
        "barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager": "0.2.x",
        "psy/psysh": "^0.7.2"
      },
      "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
          "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
          "App\\": "app/"
        }
      },
      "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
          "php artisan clear-compiled",
          "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [

        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
          "php artisan clear-compiled",
          "php artisan optimize",
          "php artisan serve"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
          "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
          "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
      },
      "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
      }
}
```

i believe this is causing the error: 
            **"terbium/db-config": "^2.0",**

usage example: **getcong('p-news')**

thank you.

Comment: Did you backup any of your data at any point?

Comment: Are you using a version control tool?

Comment: NO :( I don't have backup or version control.

Comment: Well, I guess that's a good lesson: Always use version control. I'm not aware of any way to generate a `composer.json` (or `composer.lock`) from a `vendor/` directory.

Comment: i believe this is causing the error: 
            **"terbium/db-config": "^2.0",**

Comment: @Chris

thank you for your help :)

Comment: Be sure to check your recycle bin!

Answer (score 0):

I need to add

```
 "files": [
        "app/Http/helpers.php"
    ]
```

to composer file :)